# Is it possible to popup a win form without freeze the excel?

Tags: winforms, excel, vba

Is it possible to popup a win form without freeze the excel?

I create button in the excel, when I click on the button, it popup a winform.

However, it freeze the "background" excel, I cannot select data from the "background" excel until I close the winform, so is it possible to fix the problem?

I am using the following code to popup the winform

```
  UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: Use the Form.Modal property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172748(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I found a ShowModal property in the winform, I set it to false, it works.

thank you very much